# How to Set FormLoad Value of a drop down usng jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**VIEW**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        var id = $("#ddlSection").val();
        $.getJSON("../QuizMaker/PopulateSubjects", { id: id },
               function (subjectData) {
                   var select = $("#ddlSubject");
                   select.empty();
                   select.append($('<option/>', {
                       value: 0,
                       text: "Select a Subject"
                   }));
                   $.each(subjectData, function (index, itemData) {
                       select.append($('<option/>', {
                           value: itemData.Value,
                           text: itemData.Text
                       }));
                   });
               });
        //$('#ddlSubject').val("15").attr("selected", "selected");

        //$("#ddlSubject").selectmenu('refresh');
});

</script>

@*<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlSubject').val("15")

    $("#ddlSubject").selectmenu('refresh');
    //$("#ddlSubject").val("15").change();
});*@


@*</script>*@

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlSubject').val(15).attr("selected", "selected");

    $("#ddlSubject").selectmenu('refresh');
    //$("#ddlSubject").val("15").change();
});

</script>

    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sectionID, new SelectList(Model.Sections, "sec_id", "sec_name"), "Select a Section", new { id = "ddlSection" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sectionID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.subjectID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "text", "value"), "Select a Subject", new { id = "ddlSubject" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subjectID)
    </div>
```

@* were comments. but I can't seem to find the right way to show initial value of my dropdown i've set one of the value of my dropdown item to 15 but the dropdown won't reflect it on load. i tried the one's that are in comment but it won't work....

Comment: ajax is asynchronous (your setting the value before the options have been created). Set it in the success callback of the `$.getJSON()` method (after your `$.each()` loop). But what is the point of this - your just loading the options as soon as the page is loaded. Pass a populated `SelectList` to your `DropDownListFor()` method and delete all the scripts you have shown.

Comment: yes i was loading it but i want it to have a onLoad value coming from the values of the dropdown

Comment: What? I don't understand your comment, but its clear you do not understand waht your doing here. All the scripts you have shown are unnecessary.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i've tried you solution it worked thanks a lot :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke the success: solved it :)

Comment: I'm guessing you have not shown the real code, and that the script you have shown is really not running when the page is loaded, but in response to selecting an option in the first dropdown. And set the value of the first ("Select a Subject") option to `value: ''` (not value: 0`) so an error is added to `ModelState` if its selected